# Vim Swap Files Not Deleting

Tags: vim, macvim

Vim is not deleting .swp files when I quit. I am using vim in iTerm (macvim) and quitting with `:q` or `:wq` or `:qa`. My swap files seem to be sticking around. I have had to ad `*.swp *.swo *.swn` to my .gitignore which is becoming frustrating to say the least and I'm sure it's confusing my clients and coworkers. They are filling my computer with needless files. And of course I have to step through the "Swap file exists" warning every time I open a file.

I'd like swap files to delete on quit. Failing that I'd like to find some way to clean them up automatically.

What are my options for diagnosing/solving this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can capture a full log of a Vim session with `vim -V20vimlog`. After quitting Vim, examine the `vimlog` log file for suspect messages. I could imagine that even though Vim is able to *create* the swap files, it is somehow not able to *delete* them.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem (on a linux machine).
For some reason, after editing files in a specific directory vim didn't delete the .swp files. The `vimlog` provided no useful information. 
 However, deleting `~/.viminfo` fixed it!

Answer (score -1):

the file system was full in my case and vim was writing (or attempting to write) on both .[file].swp and /var/tmp/[file].swp. After cleaning up the file system vim was back to normal.